# Importing content files from a nuget directory into a particular directory

Tags: css, nuget

I have a nuget package with some css files included in it as content files.

I want the css files to be created in a particular directory when the package is imported into a project. I'd rather not have the project that the css files belong to structured in exactly the same way.

Is there a way to set a target directory for the content files that are added? I tried doing this:

```
<file src="typography\*.css" target="content\css\jobseekerstyle-$version$\typography" />
```

But then the files ended up being included twice, once where I wanted them and once where they exist in the project.

The package is for managing CSS and only contains content files, so maybe there is a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for your post.

we have a duplicate bug filed on codeplex as https://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/1914. The issue is currently to be fixed in NuGet 2.9 release.